# setting trackpad tapping default value with xinput

Tags: arch-linux, xinput

It seems to be a common issue not to be able to set certain values with `xinput`.
So today I booted up my laptop and trackpad tapping didn't work.
I looked at the `xinput` table and noticed that the option numbers had changed, which seems kinda strange to me.
Running `xinput --list-props 11` I get the following output

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (165):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (167): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (300): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (301): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (302):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (303):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (304):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (305):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (306):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (307):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (308):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (309):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (310):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (311):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (312):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (313):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (314):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (315): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (316):    1, 0
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (317):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (318):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (319):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (320): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (321): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (322): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (323): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (285): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (286):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (287):    0, 0
    Device Node (288):  "/dev/input/event7"
    Device Product ID (289):    2, 7
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (324):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (325):   1
```

Until yesterday the `300` value was `286` and similarly all other values were 14 lower.

When I run `xinput --set-prop 11 301 1` I get

```
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  20
```

Running it with `sudo` also doesn't help.
I did a bit of research about this issue but I could not find any fix for this.
So my workaround at the moment is to put `xinput --set-prop 11 300 1` in my xmonad config which runs on startup to enable trackpad tapping.
Yet I wonder if there is any fix for this.
Before it was `xinput --set-prop 11 286 1`, so it didn't work today since the numbers had changed.
I know it isn't really a problem, but it bothers me a little, but I'd rather have a fix than putting this in one of my startup scripts.

I'm running Arch linux on a ThinkPad x260, not sure if this might be relevant.
I also had this issue with other distros like Fedora, ArchLabs and Antergos.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting.

So my gut feeling was right in referencing properties only by name, which is perfectly fine with `xinput` (makes it more readable too).

In your case:

```
xinput --set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "libinput Tapping Enabled" 1
```

Comment: I see, thanks for the tip, this seems like a good work around to the number thing.
But my other issue remains namely that I want it to be active by **default**, not enable it every time on start up

Comment: I don't know of any other way to tell the driver to enable it by default other than to put it into a `.xsessionrc` file in your home dir, sry.